# Rails How to test a method receives block argument with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, block

Lets say I have this in application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    def example(&block)
        ...code here
    end
end
```

and this in another controller:

```
class OtherController < ApplicationController

    def index
        example { some_text("irrelevant_text") }
    end

    private

    def some_text var
        "#{var}_string"
    end
end
```

I want to test that when calling the index action `example` method gets called with the **irrelevant_text_string** argument.

Something like:

```
describe 'index' do
    it 'should call example' do
        controller.should_receive(:example).with("irrelevant_text_string")
        get :index
    end
end
```

But this isn't working. I keep getting

```
received :example with unexpected arguments
expected: ("irrelevant_text_string")
          got: (no args)
```

Why does it say no args?
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score -1):

Because you are passing a block to it, not an argument.

Comment: Ok, and how can I test the method receives the correct block?